# ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'ILLEGAL'

Tags: solidity, parse-error

```
Error: ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'ILLEGAL'
   --> 22omo.sol:560:10:
    |
560 | contract 2omo is Context, IERC20, Ownable {
    |          ^
```

CODE (to note this is not line 1):

```
contract 2omo is Context, IERC20, Ownable {

    using SafeMath for uint256;

    IUniswapV2Router02 private _uniswapV2Router;

    IERC20 private WrappedETH;
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's possible that a contract name can't start with a number